# Check if many to many child objects share a parent in Django

Tags: python, django, orm

I have these simple models in Django. Given two accounts `acc1` and `acc2`, what is the best way to figure out if they are both participating in the same team? I'm trying to keep this as concise as possible (because this was to be a lambda, no named variables).

```
class Team(models.Model):
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Account, through='Participation')

class Participation(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

So far what I've got:

```
def are_in_same_team(acc_pk1, acc_pk2):
    teams = Team.objects.filter(participation__account__id__in=[acc_pk1, acc_pk2])
    return (acc_pk1 == acc_pk2 and len(teams) == 1) or (len(teams) == 2 and teams[0] == teams[1])
```

Comment: Try `return acc1.team == acc2.team`

Comment: An account can have many teams, so instead the object has a `team_set`. What you're suggesting cannot be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check if there exists a team which have both the members:

```
def are_in_same_team(acc_pk1, acc_pk2):
    return Team.objects.filter(members__id=acc_pk1).filter(members__id=acc_pk2).exists()
```